# sublime like text selection for intellij missing

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

in intellij ultimate 2018.1

I was reading here:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text-style-multiple-selections/

> Add/remove a selection: Alt + Shift + Mouse Click

I cannot find an action called like that, even when trying hard to look for it

the mouse shortcut / key shortcut is bound to something else in my case something like add caret

what do I want?

if you have this:

```
<div></div>
<span></span>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

select all div, then deselect the middle 2 ones
so:

[] marks selection:

```
<[div]></[div]>
<span></span>
<div></div>
<[div]></[div]>
```

idea would be

select first `div` then do 'select all occurrences' then remove the middle ones by clicking on them

but: this action seems to be missing

Answer (score 0):

The action is called `Add or Remove Caret`. So you can position your text cursor/caret on a div tag, invoke `Select All Occurrences` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on the Mac). And then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse Click</kbd> on the carets you don't need.

Comment: Note that unselecting works only on click on the caret, not the entire selection.

Comment: @Toskan try to look for the action in `all actions` list  (shift+cmd(ctrl)+a) or everywhere with double-shift.